# NextJS 14: How to share data between components when using app router?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, app-router

I just 20 days old into nextjs so I may be missing quite a few thing.
I have a dashboard page server side rendered which has 3 components.
I have a component (tsx) with a button which when clicked should update a table on another component on the dashboard.

What is the best way to implement if server side rendering and using the 3 component is a mandatory?
Do I need to use something 3rd party like redux or app router is well equipped to achieve this

I am using nextjs 14 (app router) with typescript

[basic ui diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3UlB.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If Component 3 and Component 2 do not have a common parent, then you could use either

1. Context / Provider
2. Third party state libraries like (Redux, Zustand)

If they have a common parent, then you could just have a state at the common parent and pass handler functions to set the state on Component 3 and the state itself to Component 2.

Comment: thanks for looking into it. Context will not be available for server-side rendered?
can you share some link to read on passing handler function

Comment: Yes. Context will not be available on the server but only on the client.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
const FirstPageComponent = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const handleClick = () => {
        router.push({
            pathname: "/sencondPage",
            query: { data: "" },
        });
    };
    return <button onClick={handleClick}>Go to Second Page</button>;
};
// Component in Second Page
const SecondPageComponent = ({ data }) => {
    return <div>Data from First Page: {data}</div>;
};

export default SecondPageComponent;

// Set data in First page
localStorage.setItem("Key", "data");

// Get data in Second Page
const data = localStorage.getItem("key");
```

Comment: second page? there is no second page to goto

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).